# UIButton show selected state on tap

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6

How do I show the selected state for the UIButton on tap?

I want it so that when people tap on the uibutton it shows the selected state with the hover that I have?

Right now they have to hold the button to see the hover.

```
[t1 setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"hover.png"]] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

I want to show the hover image on tap also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the selected state for the button

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hover.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

To show a hoover image while the button is pressed you need to set the state property to `UIControlStateHighlighted`

Comment: Setting the state on the button to `UIControlStateHighlighted` did not change the state of the button while being pressed?

Comment: No it does not highlight when tapped but when pressed it does.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - my button was highlighted when pressed (tap+hold) and wasn't - when simply tapped. Here is my code:

```
btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        UIImage *image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn"];
        UIImage *imageSelected =[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_tap"];
        [btn setBackgroundImage:transImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setBackgroundImage:imageSelected forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)btnPressedWithDelay{
    //your code for btn action
}

- (void) action:(UIButton *)sender{
    [self performSelector:@selector(btnPressedWithDelay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

Did it work for you?